# Are datasources other than Mongo available with Meteor?

Tags: meteor

Can I use datasources other than Mongo with Meteor? If so, where can I find an example? I'm specifically looking for MySQL, Memcache, and/or Redis support.

Answer (score 7):

At the moment, you'd have to build a 'driver' to attach any additional data sources to Meteor.

That said, they've defined a 'DDP' protocol, but if it's been documented, I haven't seen it on the web.

If you look at the existing code for the local_collection_driver, you may be able to get a sense of how to do it:

- https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/master/packages/mongo-livedata/local_collection_driver.js
- https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/master/packages/mongo-livedata/mongo_driver.js

Answer (score 2):

In addition to DDP there is Meteor-SQL : https://github.com/drorm/meteor-sql

Which lets you connect to mysql databases quite nicely with meteor.

Answer (score 1):

This is a DDP client written in python: [Python DDP](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/master/examples/unfinished/python-ddp-client/ddp-client.py)

I am going to be working with it in the next couple hours.

Over beers, I have heard that a spec for DDP is in the works.

Answer (score 0):

Redis support is in development but already supports strings and hashes: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/meteor-core/Jl5Jt739wdA